# Empty directory (delete all files)

Tags: ruby

What would be a safe and efficient way to delete all files in a directory in pure Ruby? I wrote

```
Dir.foreach(dir_path) {|f| File.delete(f) if f != '.' && f != '..'}
```

but it gives me a `No such file or directory` error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably getting that error because your current working directory doesn't match `dir_path` -- `File.delete(f)` is being given just the filename for a file in `dir_path`. (I hope you didn't have any important files in the current working directory with same names in the `dir_path` directory.)

You need to use `File.join(dir_path, f)` to construct the filename you wish to delete. You also need to figure out how you want to handle directories:

```
Dir.foreach(dir_path) do |f|
  fn = File.join(dir_path, f)
  File.delete(fn) if f != '.' && f != '..'
end

Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory - /tmp/testing/blubber
    from (irb):10:in `delete'
    from (irb):10
    from (irb):10:in `foreach'
    from (irb):10
    from :0
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! In my case there won't be subdirectories in the `dir_path` directory, as it is used for storing temporal files. In case there would be directories I suppose adding a condition to the inline if like `!File.directory?(fn)` would work. Is it right or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that should do nicely -- and also let you skip the `.` and `..` tests, since they will both test as directories.

Answer (score 77):

What about `FileUtils.rm_rf("#{dir_path}/.", secure: true)`?

Comment: Seems to work also, but I think I prefer to use `Dir` as it is a core class.

Comment: FileUtils is part of Ruby's standard library, and, as such, is automatically included with an installation of Ruby. Whether it's "core" or not isn't really an issue since it'll be available either way, and only needs `require 'fileutils'` to make it available.

Comment: Strange thing on windows it will lead to directory delete (not just make it empty), tested on ruby 2.5, 2.4, 2.3

Answer (score 34):

```
FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{dir_path}/*") if dir_path.present?
```

Comment: This method for me is prettier than highest-rated one, because it lets you use `Dir.glob`'s magic. For example, if you have nested directories and want to delete only files in them to keep directory tree - use `FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{dir_path}/*/*.*")`. 

`Dir.glob` will also omit any dot-prefixed files - this is really handy if you want to keep the `.keep` files.

Comment: What if `dir_path` is `nil` because of a typo or other error?  *Most* of the time ruby code isn't run as root, right?

Comment: @gtd Thanks for comment. Yes in this case ```Dir.glob``` returns all directories in ```/``` folder. And I assume that it is not good :)

Answer (score 11):

Everybody suggest `rm_rf`, but the safer way is to use `rm_f`, which is an alias to `rm force: true`.

```
FileUtils.rm_f Dir.glob("#{dir_path}/*")
```

This method will not remove directories, it will only remove files: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm

Comment: Along the same lines, I don't understand why anyone is using the force option to begin with. Except in special cases, you shouldn't be having permission issues, otherwise you have an actual environment issue that should be resolved first. Forcing removals is a recipe for disaster, and the safer option is to use *rm*, or *rm_r* for recursive.

Answer (score 4):

Now days, I like using the [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html) class when working on files or directories.

This should get you started:

```
Pathname.new(dir_path).children.each { |p| p.unlink }
```

[`unlink`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-unlink) will remove directories or files, so if you have nested directories you want to preserve you'll have to test for them:

> Removes a file or directory, using File.unlink if self is a file, or Dir.unlink as necessary.

Comment: The OP says "delete all files in a directory", and doesn't mention wanting to delete the directory itself. The code deletes all files, and does not recurse into child directories, nor does it delete the containing directory. How is that "almost right"?

Comment: Because it breaks as soon as there is a directory in it. If you want to take it literally you at least would have to filter out directories.

Answer (score 4):

To tack on to MyroslavN, if you wanted to do it with Pathname (like with Rails.root, if it's a rails app) you want this:

```
FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('foo', 'bar', '*'))
```

I'm posting this because I did a bad copypaste of his answer, and I accidentally wound up with an extra slash in my path:

```
Rails.root.join('foo', 'bar', '/*')
```

Which evaluates to `/*` because it sees it as a root path. And if you put that in the `FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob` it will attempt to recursively delete everything it can (probably limited by your permissions) in your filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

The Tin Man almost got it right - but in case the directories are not empty use

```
Pathname.new(dir_path).children.each { |p| p.rmtree }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation that's nice and succinct if you only have files or empty directories:

```rb
your_path.children.each.map(&:unlink)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dir.foreach(dir_path) {|f| File.delete("#{dir_path}/#{f}") if f != '.' && f != '..'}
```

Comment: Welcome Ali to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Its best to give code answers some context with some writing to explain it. Also to format to make a code snippet use the ` single quote around your code.